# Up-to-date Django-Facebook-Heroku Tutorial

Tags: python, django, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

I am trying to learn 3 tools at once, and I am in deep misery. Is there any up-to-date tutorial to build a simple Django app that uses Facebook Graph API and runs on Heroku?

Comment: I would not recommend learning Heroku, for your use, until you A) understand Django, B) slightly understand Graph, C) understand how to deploy your application (even a simplistic version) on something like Ubuntu (i.e., not a fully managed solution like Heroku). The reason for C is because Heroku will only take you so far, and once you reach that point, if you have no other experience, you'll run into a brick wall.

Comment: I am running other Flask apps on Heroku. I did the Django tutorial and a ribbit from Nettuts. Code wise I get what's going on. But the hard part is to connect all these together. Django has a lot of things running in the background and it's hard to understand where the problems are when I run into a brick wall.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your approach is to broad. I would recommend learning each piece individually then piecing them together.

The official [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) is a good place to start for that piece. I'm not experienced with either of the others so I have no links to provide.

Remember, sometimes shortcuts take longer. Learn how to use each tool properly and you'll come out ahead in the end and will probably take less time to develop you're final application.

Comment: I've managed to run build my Facebook app with Flask-OAuth and FacePy libraries on Flask. I guess next step is to try them combine all this with Django.